# How to make an if statement work if a message starts the prefix + a command using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello I've switched from working with discord.py to discord.js for my discord bot. Im having trouble currently, i want a feature of my bot to be able to be given a sentence beginning with a command and prefix (for example *say Hello world) then I want the bot to remove the prefix and command and send the rest of the content back.

However I can't seem to get the if statement to work vie tried this

```
if (msg.content.startsWith == prefix + 'say')
```

which is similar to pythons syntax but doesn't seem to trigger if I use this, I want to be able to type something like this (*say hello world) and the if statement should trigger because the first thing in the message is the command, however it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startsWith` is not a property, it's a function.

You can achieve your goal by either using `startsWith()`

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}say`))
```

Or you can just check if the `message.content` is equal to `${prefix}say`

```js
if (msg.content === `${prefix}say`)
```

Comment: Yeah I realised I literally just had to put brackets in, im spending a bit more time on my problems now before posting any questions. Thanks